# Recommend making "city-design" a synonym of "city"

Tags: support, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

I've been working with tag wikis and just completed filling out the fields for [city](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city).  Next on the list is [city-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city-design).

I was going to identify [city-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city-design) as a synonym of [city](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city) (which puts it up for community vote to approve/reject the synonym association), but it won't let me as I don't have a score of 5 in [city](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city).

If a mod or anyone with a score of 5 in [city](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city) agrees that [city-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city-design) could our should be a synonym of [city](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city), would you be willing to make the assignment and invoke the vote?

Comment: I support the idea, I would help if I had the score.

Comment: I was looking at the tags and noticed that [city] and [cities] are very similar and was going to create a question about it but saw this one.  I see that @JBH recently created [city] so I'd like to ask about that and see if there is a way to reduce confusion about these tags with similar names and overlapping descriptions.  Can you tell me more about the reasons for creating [city] when we had [cities]?  Thanks.

Comment: @Cyn, I didn't create the tag - I only filled in its wiki.  I'm all for creating synonyms (which I prefer over merging.  If someone created the tag originally, it'll get created again).  I don't know the site's preference, but my own is to favor the singular over the plural.  But that's just me.

Comment: I see.  I completely see how separating out the design of a city from questions about existing cities makes sense.  But you changed [city-design] to [city] and now there is the confusion with [cities].  What would you recommend?  (Also, please vote on my [mythical-creatures]/[fantasy-races] proposal...in WB not Meta...I don't know if I get notifications about it or not.)

Comment: @Cyn, simpler is better.  There's not enough of a difference between development-new and management-existing to justify separate tags in my mind.  And I already have upvoted the mythical creatures post.  I'm in favor.

Comment: Then should we combine [city] and [cities]?  That makes sense to me.  For the other, I mean this page: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/mythical-creatures/synonyms

Comment: @Cyn Yes and ah-hah!  I just voted.

Comment: How do we proceed with the cit* tags?  A new meta post?  Directly going to [cities] and proposing that [city] is a synonym?  As far as I can tell, there is no notification to people that there's a vote going on.  I've never seen one and you and others didn't see mine (I did edit my meta post to reflect it, but that still requires people to look at it again).

Comment: @Cyn, I'd propose city as a synonym (I couldn't do it at the time I posted this Q as I didn't have enough points in that tag).  And you're right, I've never seen the synonym votes - there isn't a review queue for them (at least for non-mods, I wonder if mods can see them?)  Let's ask a CVn.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough points in either of those tags myself (4 in city and 0 in cities).

Answer (score 3):

Generally, tag synonyms aren't used for significant substring matches. This would make *city-design* a poor synonym for *city*, as if the two are separate anyone typing *city* into the tags field will get suggestions for *city* and *city-design*. An example of a better synonym could be, say, *village* or *homestead* (none of which exist at this point) to *city*, since (say) someone who types *village* wouldn't otherwise know that the proper tag is *city*.

I haven't looked at the two tags in detail, but I do note that we have at this time:

- 4 questions tagged [city](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city)
- 5 questions tagged [city-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city-design)
- 0 questions tagged both [city](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city) and [city-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city-design)

I don't see any obvious reason why we should have both, however, so I'd be inclined to just **merge the two tags.** **Since there are so few questions involved,** this is something the community could easily do.

I'd probably be inclined to keep [city](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city) while letting [city-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city-design) die the honorable death by question edits.

Comment: Merging would be as good a solution as using a synonym.  The way the two tags were being used appeared entirely redundant to me.

Comment: Cyn and I have been discussing this issue in comments above and we have a question.  Do mods have a review queue for synonyms? or is that feature kinda out-of-sight/out-of-mind?